# Drupal 9 404 error on POST to /user/login

Tags: drupal

Site /user/login loads fine, but when the form is filled and posted, the POST is coming up as a 404 in the Nginx error logs, /user/login is reloaded with NO error message.

Site is a local network duplication of production site BUT `/sites/default` settings files etc are set up for the local environment.

`core/modules/user/user.routing.yaml` has the POST method in `user/login` path pointing to the correct controller - that's all vanilla.

- Tried posting with usual credentials, always redirected to /user/login page with no error message (instead of being logged in)
- Used drush uli <username> to create a login one-time URI and could login with that

Comment: is there any nginx error log. try any other form like forgot password or registration form if you are getting same error then check php configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To reset Password using - `drush >=10.x.x`

Use the command

`$ drush upwd 1 "123"`

Here `1` stands for the user-id, the admin user obviously is with id `1`, and then the quoted text is password.

Comment: Credentials aren't the issue. For some reason, getting a 404 error when trying to POST to user/login (but NOT during a GET)